# iOS facebook login response does not contain profile data

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook-login

I implemented Facebook login for both Android and iOS using [react-native-facebook-login](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login). I followed all of the instructions and it is working perfectly on Android. It works on iOS, but the response does not contain `profile` data.

Android Response:

```
declinedPermissions: [],
provider: 'facebook',
profile:{ 
id: '121212121212121212',
name: 'XYZ',
email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
first_name: 'XYZ',
last_name: 'XYZ',
age_range: { min: 21 },
link: 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/121212121212121212/',
picture: { data: { is_silhouette: false,url: 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/12/12.jpg?oh=12&oe=12' } },
gender: 'male',
locale: 'en_US',
timezone: 5.5,
updated_time: '2017-02-01T08:16:35+0000',verified: true },
type: 'success',
credentials: { 
permissions: [ 'public_profile', 'contact_email', 'user_friends', 'email' ],
tokenExpirationDate: '2017-05-13T14:56:36.690+0530',
userId: '1212121212121212121',
token:'ababababababababbababababa' }
```

But on iOS, the response is incomplete and there is no profile data:

```
declinedPermissions: [],
credentials: { tokenExpirationDate: '2017-05-14T14:58:09+05:30',
permissions: [ 'email', 'contact_email', 'user_friends', 'public_profile' ],
userId:'12121212121212121',
token:'abababababababababababababa' },
missingPermissions: []
```

The code is same for both Android and iOS. And I did all of the configuration changes in Xcode. Is there something else that needs to be done to get the profile data on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to do another API call where we send the token which was generated into this API call.

```
fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=email,name,first_name,last_name,friends&access_token=' + YOUR_GENERATED_TOKEN)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
    })
    .catch(() => {
      reject('ERROR')
    })
```

This call will give you the profile details.